# How can I fix this short snippet of VB that was translated from C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, extension-methods, c#-to-vb.net

I was given this snippet of C# that works perfectly in Visual Studio 2010:

using System;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void RequestLanguageChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton senderLink = (LinkButton)sender;
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.ApplyCultureToUrl(senderLink.CommandArgument));
}
}
```

And every online converter (and SharpDevelop) translates it to this in VB:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Partial Class MasterPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Protected Sub RequestLanguageChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim senderLink As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)

Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl.ApplyCultureToUrl(senderLink.CommandArgument))
End Sub
End Class
```

VS also is doing the same with this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Localization
Private Sub New()
End Sub
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Shared Function ApplyCultureToUrl(rawUrl As String, culture As String) As String
Dim modifiedUrl As String
```

Saying **System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension** can only be run in modules.

**The Problem:**

In Visual Studio 2010, **Request.RawUrl.ApplyCultureToUrl** is underlined in blue, and it doesn't offer a solution.  It just says **ApplyCultureToUrl is not a member of 'String'**.  This is the only thing stopping my solution from working!

I researched on MSDN, and it says that the error means it must be surrounded by a module, but not being a coder, I have no idea how to fix it.  The snippet is to help my ?lang=en-GB querystring show up in my multilingual website.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

---

Update:  I have the ApplyCulturetoUrl thing working, just by clicking a lot of icons in Visual Studio, and it spit this out:

```
Partial Public Class MasterPage
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub

Protected Sub RequestLanguageChange_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim senderLink As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
    Response.Redirect(ApplyCultureToUrl(Request.RawUrl, senderLink.CommandArgument))
End Sub

Private Sub body()
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub

Private Function ApplyCultureToUrl(p1 As String, p2 As String) As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
End Class
```

And that's giving me no errors, although I don't know if it's correct ... hehe .... Now, the only other part of the code that's giving me an error is in localization.vb, a class, and it's like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Localization
Private Sub New()
End Sub
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Shared Function ApplyCultureToUrl(rawUrl As String, culture As String) As String
 Dim modifiedUrl As String
```

And System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension() is underlined in squiggly blue and it says Extension methods can only be defined in modules.  I'm using all of your suggestions!  Thank you for sticking with it!

Comment: I have a feeling this will be an extension method, defined elsewhere in the other project. In the C# solution, right-click and select 'Go to definition', this should help you find it.

Comment: Hey, Disappointment, I think you're right!  When I go to definition, there are a bevy of options, and I'm not sure which to choose!  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ApplyCultureToUrl` is an extension method.

Solving this could be as easy as importing the namespace in which `ApplyCultureToUrl` is defined.

However it may be more complex than this:

In VB.Net extensions methods have to be in a module, this has to be public to reference the extension from other projects. To include them you just need to reference the containing assembly and import the right namespace.

The MSDN page for VB.Net Extension methods is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jon ... I'm tryin'!  The <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> is giving me the most trouble now, saying it must be defined in a module!

Comment: That's the case. Have a read through the MSDN page I linked as it covers this stuff fairly well - You need a module (not a class) in your project to define your extension method in.

Comment: It might be easier just to create a normal function and pass the script you want to change in as an argument.

Comment: @JonEgerton You can use extension methods in VB.Net written in another assembly; I do so regularly. I don't know what led you to the opposite conclusion as all assemblies are IL regardless of if the source is VB or C#.

Comment: Jon, I hate to bug you for something so simple, but what kind of argument or method could I pass to when it says System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension() is underlined in squiggly blue and it says Extension methods can only be defined in modules.?  I'm not a programmer, and our company is too small to hire one, so I'm being quite heuristic and learning by editing, uploading, and refreshing, etc. ..... thanks again for your patience, Jon!

Comment: @GideonEngelberth: I don't think you can define extension methods that in VB.Net that can be used outside of the current Assembly - the language won't support it as they have to be defined in a module and therefore aren't publicly visible. I didn't say you can't use external ones, but you'll probably find they were written in C#. Would be interested to see an example if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jason. I'm suggesting that you do what Artem has suggested. If you have problems with the extension then use a normal function as he says.

Comment: Private Function ApplyCultureToUrl(RawUrl as String, Command as String) As String
   // body
End Function ... but what would I put in the body, Jon?

Comment: @GideonEngelberth: I eat my words - you're dead right, as long as the module is public! <Takes foot from mouth>

Answer (score 1):

Put the cursor to the `ApplyCultureToUrl` keyword in C# file and hit F12 button. This method defined as an extension method somewhere.

I don't know if Visual Basic supports extension methods, if no, you can define it in VB locally:

```
Private Function ApplyCultureToUrl(RawUrl as String, Command as String) As String
   // body
End Function
```

In this case you'll call it as follows:

```
Response.Redirect(ApplyCultureToUrl(Request.RawUrl, senderLink.CommandArgument))
```

Comment: VB.Net does support extensions, but not nicely (they have to be in a module!)

Comment: That solution almost worked, Artem.  But now it underlined End Function in green, and said, 'ApplytoCultureURL' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.   Sheesh!  This is drivin' me nuts!

Comment: @JasonWeber In the answer above, where it says `\\body`, you **are** inserting some code, right? Artem wants you to find the C# extension method and translate it into VB, and put it where it says `\\body`

Comment: Mark, I'm so unintelligent when it comes to this, I do apologize.  I'm going to redo the entire thing (which isn't long -- it'll take me 10 minutes) and report back.  All of you guys are way generous for helping along with this.  I appreciate Jon, Artem, and you Mark.  I did read John's MSDN page, and I tried things, but VS keeps giving me errors.  Thank you all for your patience.   I'm redoing it now, be back in about 10!